# Ajax post call returns parsererror

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I submit the reactjs form as mentioned below,

```
submit(){    
    if(this.checkRequiredField()){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/Accounts',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {               
          Name: this.state.name, 
          StartDate :this.state.startDate, 
          EndDate : this.state.endDate,
          UserCount: this.state.userCount          
        },
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {            
        console.log('data added successfully');
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }
```

The above ajax post will call the respective Web Api post method, where the data got inserted successfully to the db.

After it posts the data, the program doesn't return to the success function, instead it calls error function and logs the error

> parsererror SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1
>   column 1 of the JSON data

when I checked the xhr.status, the value is 201 and statustext is Created.

Why the above ajax post call returns parsererror? how to fix this issue?

Comment: `/api/Accounts` isn't returning valid JSON

Comment: should I remove the dataType:'json' from the above code?

Comment: Do you expect JSON? `console.log(xhr.responseText)` or look at the request in the network panel to see what was returned.

Comment: what does `/api/Accounts` return? `dataType:'text',` is a safe option I guess

Comment: `201` don't have response body usually. Remove that `dataType` option and it will be fine.

Comment: Jaromanda X and Mathew Jibin Thanks for your help, it worked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the dataType mentioned in the ajax call.

The post method is not returning any json data, 
by changing the dataType :'json' to dataType:'text' fixed the issue.

Thanks Jaromanda X and Mathew Jibin for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you are not expecting a JSON format return, you may need to remove that instead.

```
submit(){    
    if(this.checkRequiredField()){
    $.ajax({
      url: '/api/Accounts',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {               
          Name: this.state.name, 
          StartDate :this.state.startDate, 
          EndDate : this.state.endDate,
          UserCount: this.state.userCount          
        },
      success: function(data, status, xhr) {            
        console.log('data added successfully');
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

just a suggestion,
if you want to return a json from controller you can pass a custom message from controller, like saved successfully, keeping your same ajax code

```
  success: function(data, status, xhr) {            
        console.log(data.ResponseText );
      }
```

controller:
based on condition

```
       return Json(new { success = true, 
ResponseText = "saved successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```